# C++ converting floating point to base 10 using IEEE 754

Tags: c++

i was able to show the floating point representation of a number in binary found the signbit, exponent and fraction. But if i want to convert that to  the base 10 of the signbit, exponent and fraction how would i go about doing so. An example 
can be like floating point for 12:

Sign Bit = 0

Exponent = 130

Fraction = 4194304

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
void binary(int n, int i)
{
    int k;
    for (i--; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        k = n >> i;
        if (k & 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }

}


typedef union
{
    float f;
    struct
    {
        unsigned int mantissa : 23;
        unsigned int exponent : 8;
        unsigned int sign : 1;
    } field;
} myfloat;
int main()
{
    myfloat var;
    printf("Enter any float number: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &var.f);
    cout << "SignBit = ";
    printf("%d ", var.field.sign);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Exponent = ";
    binary(var.field.exponent, 8);
    printf(" ");
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Fraction = ";
    binary(var.field.mantissa, 23);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some example output would be helpful.  Do you want to print something like 1.840 x 2^-3 or something like 2.30 * 10^-1 (same number)?

Comment: @DietrichEpp an example would be the number 12 for example the signbit = 0, exponent = 130 and fraction =  4194304

Comment: Your union solution is wrong because UB.

Comment: @deviantfan: It's only technically undefined behavior.  It's common practice, it's codified in parallel standards (C99, C11) and it's explicitly supported by most compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Just print them.

```
cout << var.field.mantissa << ' ' << var.field.exponent << ' ' << var.field.sign << '\n';
```